# Count Uppercase and Lowercase Letters without using RegEx in php

Tags: php, string, string-matching

How do I count Uppercase and Lowercase letters and numbers in a string **without** using regular expressions?

Comment: What do you have against Regex?! ^.^

Comment: create an array for all alphabets in upper case use `in_array` for check each char of string.

Comment: Most people wouldn't, they'd just use regexp; but easy enough to do: array_count_values()  is helpful

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: ya.. it is an assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string    = "HelLo wOrlD";
$lowerCase = strtolower($string);
$upperCase = strtoupper($string);

$lowerDiff = similar_text($string, $lowerCase);
$upperDiff = similar_text($string, $upperCase);

echo "Capital:" . (strlen($string) - $lowerDiff); // 4
echo "<br>";
echo "Lowercase:" . (strlen($string) - $upperDiff); // 6
```

Comment: Hey! Same idea! ^.^

Comment: Accents must be caught, so use "Multibyte string functions" as `mb_strtolower` and `mb_strtoupper`. Be carreful with `similar_text` which has some weirdo results. For instance I tried with `Yolo yolO yolO yolo Yolo` and expected `4` capital letters but your answer gives me `7`: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a1f82ebecb87ed5ac02b81033856089a2c9c7d35

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way leveraging `count_chars()`, `array_filter()`, and `array_sum()`.  There will be many ways to tackle this one.

This method will get the byte values for each letter, filter against them ([ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)), then sum up the values.

```
$string="HelLo wOrlD";
$chars=count_chars($string,1);
$uppers=array_sum(array_filter($chars,function($k){return in_array($k,range(65,90));},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
var_export($uppers);
echo "\n";
$lowers=array_sum(array_filter($chars,function($k){return in_array($k,range(97,122));},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
var_export($lowers);
```

Output:

```
4
6
```

---

Here is another which offers the same result:

```
$string="HelLo wOrlD";
$upper=$lower=0;
foreach(str_split($string) as $c){
    if(ctype_upper($c)){
        ++$upper;
    }elseif(ctype_lower($c)){
        ++$lower;
    }
}
echo "Uppers = $upper, Lowers = $lower";
```

---

Here is another:

```
$string="HelLo wOrlD";
$array=str_split($string);
$uppers=sizeof(array_filter($array,'ctype_upper')); // 4
$lowers=sizeof(array_filter($array,'ctype_lower')); // 6
```

---

```
$string="HelLo wOrlD";
$array=str_split($string);
$uppers=sizeof(array_intersect($array,range('A','Z'))); // 4
$lowers=sizeof(array_intersect($array,range('a','z'))); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these functions:

```
<?
    function count_uppercase($mixed_case) {
        $lower_case = strtolower($mixed_case);
        $similar = similar_text($mixed_case, $lower_case);
        return strlen($mixed_case)-$similar;
    }

    function count_lowercase($mixed_case) {
        $upper_case = strtoupper($mixedcase);
        $similar = similar_text($mixed_case, $upper_case);
        return strlen($mixed_case)-$similar;
    }
?>
```

These functions make a new variable of whatever string and converts them all to either uppercase or lowercase (depending on which function you use) then compares the similarities between the strings, and returns the number of differences.

As an added bonus, this should also work with strings with diacritics in them.

Comment: @ADIUnitechRoR  You have awarded the green tick to an answer that made no attempt to offer an explanation.  I would urge you to consider this answer (posted around the same time) to be more deserving of the green tick.  When two answers, posted at roughly the same time, and use the same method, the tie-breaker should be quality of explanation.